# How to backup and restore Dolphin toolbar settings?

Tags: kde, gui, plasma5, settings, dolphin

After installing Dolphin I spend a lot of time customizing it, something which is normal in Plasma. But can we save these detailed changes for future use?

I am interested in backing up as many settings as possible, but I will ask here more simply about the most obvious: the toolbar buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [forum.kde.org](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=151477#p396023) I have found the answer: the file for Dolphin custom settings is

`~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/dolphin/dolphinui.rc`.